# how to get the path of the file in real device

Tags: android

i have created an android application which takes the input qrcode image from it sdcard.
i supply it as follows:

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/qr_16.png");
 LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap); 
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
```

where qr_16.png is the image i had manually loaded in to sdcard.
what should i do to run it on real device, what steps should i follow.
i am newbea in this field please help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by run it on real device?

Comment: means i am using this code to decode a image which i had manually loaded on emulator..real device means on android phone..what steps should i take to do something like this..so that it can take input of the last image clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :>**

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/2/

Comment: thanks nik..but i am using this code to decode a image which i had manually loaded on emulator..i want to test it on android phone..what steps should i take to do something like this..so that it can take input of the last image clicked.

Comment: you can do same thing for device it is easily retrieve image from sdcard.no other path for mobile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021409/cant-able-to-store-image-from-url-to-sdcard

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

to access the external SD. In Eviroment there are other methods to access different and important paths