# download pic,but the pic not show

Tags: android, bitmap

i download many images form server,some images show well,but other not show: my key code :

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale++;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}


  public class Utils {
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
{

    final int buffer_size=1024;
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;)
        {
          int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
          if(count==-1)
              break;
          os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

i also read http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066 ,in these link it used

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PatchInputStream(in));
```

but in my code i used

```
 BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
```

i donot know how to change form FileInputStream(f) to patchInputStream(in),can you give me some advice? thank you

Comment: What is patchInputStream() here?

Comment: ih the link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066

Comment: patchInputStream is extending FilterInputStream class
for more detail for that class look for
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html

Comment: yes,but you know PatchInputStream have a parameter is inputstream,FileInputStream have a parameter is File,i donot know how to give PatchInputStream a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this ::**

```
      tran_btn_skip = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tran_btn_skip);
 try {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                "http://xyz/MRESC/images/test/skip.png")
                .getContent());
        tran_btn_skip.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

where `tran_btn_skip` is `imageview` or you can take `ImageButton`

store image in sdcard ::

[save image to sdcard android Directory problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196330/save-image-to-sdcard-android-directory-problem)

Comment: you use very complex method please try this and tell me

Comment: i know you method is right,but i need to first save the pic to a dir

Comment: why you need to store in sdcard?

Comment: if the pic have in the sdcard,i cannot to download again

Comment: so what about security of your picture? any one can use it and some time user move it then it cant get local path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021409/cant-able-to-store-image-from-url-to-sdcard

Comment: i only first to download the pic,other time no need to download the pic,so that fast to show th pic and Save  network flow